# Wordpress Blog page only showing one post

Tags: php, wordpress

Im having an issue with a theme i've been customizing. My blog post only shows ( 1 ) post and i cant seem to fix the issue in Admin > Reading > Blog pages show at most. The Value only stays at "1" even after save. The code i have here is in the Loop.php

```html
<?php ?>
<article class="primary-content">
  <?php $firstClass='first-post' ; ?>

  <?php /* If there are no posts to display, such as an empty archive page */ ?>
  <?php if ( ! have_posts() ) : ?>
  <article role="main" class="the-content">
    <h1><?php _e( '404 - I&#39;m sorry but the page can&#39;t be found' ); ?></h1>
    <p>Please try searching again or head back to the homepage.</p>
  </article>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php ?>
  <?php if (is_home()): ?>
  <h1>
 <?php if ( is_day() ) : ?><?php printf( __( '<span>Daily Archive</span> %s' ), get_the_date() ); ?>
    <?php elseif ( is_month() ) : ?><?php printf( __( '<span>Monthly Archive</span> %s' ),     get_the_date('F Y') ); ?>
    <?php elseif ( is_year() ) : ?><?php printf( __( '<span>Yearly Archive</span> %s' ), get_the_date('Y') ); ?>
    <?php elseif ( is_category() ) : ?><?php echo single_cat_title(); ?>
 <?php elseif ( is_search() ) : ?><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?>
 <?php elseif ( is_home() ) : ?>Blog<?php else : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</h1>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php /* How to display standard posts and search results */ ?>

  <article class="article-archive <?php echo $firstClass; ?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <?php $firstClass="" ; ?>
    <?php ?>
    <?php if (is_front_page()) { ?>
    <div class="home-summary">
      <?php } else { ?>
      <div class="entry-summary">
        <?php } ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( '%s' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
          <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'flozo-thumb');?>
        </a>
        <?php if (is_front_page()) { ?>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( '%s' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <?php if ( is_home() ) : ?>
        <p class="entry-meta">
          <time datetime="<?php the_time('l, F jS, Y') ?>" pubdate>
            <?php the_time( 'l jS F Y') ?>
          </time>
        </p>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
  </article>

  <?php /*?>
  <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
  <?php */?>


  <?php endwhile; // End the loop. Whew. ?>

  <?php /* Display navigation to next/previous pages when applicable */ ?>
  <?php if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
  <div class="navigation">
    <div class="nav-previous">
      <?php next_posts_link( __( 'Older posts' ) ); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-next">
      <?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts' ) ); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- #nav-below -->
  <?php endif; ?>
</article>
```

Any and all help with be greatly appreciated! Sorry if this was posted already.

- L